# Get parameter pack from boost mp_list

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-mp11

I'm struggling to filter a parameter pack while keeping it as a parameter pack.

Using boost::mp11, I have created a filtered mp_list of the parameter pack, but I don't know how to then use this list in a fold expression.

```cpp
template <typename... MyTypes>
class Foo
{
  public:
    static std::vector<Bar> getBars()
    {
      std::vector<Bar> bars;
      using filtered = boost::mp11::mp_filter<is_barable, boost::mp11::mp_list<MyTypes...>>;
      (bars.push_back(filtered::bar()), ...);
      return bar;
    }
};
```

Assuming `is_barable` is `std::true_type` when `MyTypes` has an appropriate static `Bar bar();` method, and is `std::false_type` otherwise.

The above does not compile because `filtered` isn't seen as a parameter pack which can be expanded. Is there a way to take a parameter pack from the `mp_list`?

So far my best attempt is to use an intermediate lambda template which is pretty ugly IMO, but I can't manage it any other way:

```cpp
template <typename... MyTypes>
class Foo
{
  public:
    static std::vector<Bar> getBars()
    {
      std::vector<Bar> bars;
      using filtered = boost::mp11::mp_filter<is_barable, boost::mp11::mp_list<MyTypes...>>;

      auto foo = [&bars]<typename... Ts>(boost::mp11::mp_list<Ts...>)
      {
        (bars.push_back(Ts::bar()), ...);
      };
      foo(filtered{});

      return bar;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the lambda template is barable *(pun intended)*. Alternatively, you could not transform the filtered list back to a parameter pack at all, but use `std::apply` or `tuple_apply` from mp11. https://godbolt.org/z/Kvb4Y789M. It is not much prettier though.

Comment: [`tuple_apply`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#tuple_applyf_tp) or `tuple_for_each` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mp_for_each`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_for_eachlf) to iterate over `filtered` types

```
static std::vector<Bar> getBars()
{
  std::vector<Bar> bars;
  using filtered = boost::mp11::mp_filter<is_barable, boost::mp11::mp_list<MyTypes...>>;
  boost::mp11::mp_for_each<filtered>([&]<class T>(T){
    bars.push_back(T::bar());
  });
  return bars;
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I also found that to avoid calling the constructor of each of MyTypes, the `mp_for_each<filtered>` template can be replaced with `mp_for_each<mp_transform<mp_identity, filtered>>`, then the lambda body can call `T::type::bar()`. Assuming that `::bar()` is static.